# Skipping store queue searches in Gem5 when issuing loads causes crashes in guest

Tags: c++, cpu-architecture, gem5

I'm modifying Gem5 (version 22.0.0.1) for a research project and one thing I'm testing is using special loads which when issued do not search the store queue for a potential store forward.

I've implemented this with a goto in `LSQUnit::read​` in `lsq_unit.cc`​ from right before the loop that searches the store queue (starting line 1390) to the end of the loop, where the cache access is implemented (line 1568).

```cpp
//The load_idx=isnt->lqIdx from the LSQ::pushRequest
Fault
LSQUnit::read(LSQRequest *request, ssize_t load_idx)
{
    LQEntry& load_entry = loadQueue[load_idx];
    const DynInstPtr& load_inst = load_entry.instruction();

    load_entry.setRequest(request);

    ...

    auto store_it = load_inst->sqIt;
    assert (store_it >= storeWBIt);
    /*=== my goto === */
    if (load_inst->isSpecbCheck()){
        goto cache;
    }
    /*=== store queue search loop ===*/
    // End once we've reached the top of the LSQ
    while (store_it != storeWBIt && !load_inst->isDataPrefetch()) {
        // Move the index to one younger
        store_it--;
        assert(store_it->valid());
        assert(store_it->instruction()->seqNum < load_inst->seqNum);
        int store_size = store_it->size();

        ...

    }

    /*=== code which performs cache access ===*/
    cache:

    // If there's no forwarding case, then go access memory
    DPRINTF(LSQUnit, "Doing memory access for inst [sn:%lli] PC %s\n",
            load_inst->seqNum, load_inst->pcState());

    ...
}
```

For some reason this change has caused Gem5 to crash fairly often. I'm running Spec2017 using simpoints and around 40% of generated checkpoints crash with the following error:

`build/ARM/sim/faults.cc:102: panic: panic condition !handled && !tc->getSystemPtr()->trapToGdb(SIGSEGV, tc->contextId()) occurred: Page table fault when accessing virtual address 0x54000000540​`

This only happens with checkpoints containing my new load instruction opcode, and not checkpoints without them (which are also otherwise identical). Furthermore these broken checkpoints run fine again as soon as this goto statement is removed.

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening? I've tried reading through the store forwarding code and can't figure out why skipping it altogether could cause any problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your modified code or source code with the post. It's difficult to understand the problem without sample code .

Comment: Also, how did you handle dependency. If a store in the queue and you have a dependent load, gem5 should issue the load as data is available for forwarding. Now if you do not forward the data, how do you ensure your load execution does not get the old value from the queue and issue Processor read to cache when queue is clear?

Comment: Added in code, hope this helps. I'd recommend looking up the git repo directly at the lines I mentioned if you want the full view though. As for the dependency, I'm essentially forcing a speculation by assuming no matching store will be found. If the speculation is wrong, this is caught at commit time and gem5 will roll back.

Comment: Within LSQUnit::read() , I could not find if any virtual address to physical address translation happening but based on your error, seems like it's related to that. Seems like when you are passing request to cache, page fault occurs and it is not handled properly. Try to ensure you pass memory address properly and also poke around virtual address to physical address translation and how it is simulated for gem5 O3. Also check , when you jump to cache, do you skip any code relevant to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did manage to solve this eventually so will share the problem:

When a memory order violation occurs, it's detected by an executing store searching the load queue for older loads that share an address with the store. If a load is newer and shares an address, it will forward it's value from the store. However I was disabling this process, expecting the violation to be found later on at commit. It turns out though, in gem5 at least, the only check for this happens as the store is executed and nowhere else, so any loads that were skipping store queue searches but were really dependent on an issued store were using invalid values without causing any rollback!

As such the fix to my problem was changing how this search for violations was done (or in my case specifically, still running the same store queue searching code for my special loads, pretending like I hadn't in the statistics, and then forcing a violation to occur if a matching address was found).

Edit: Was suggested I share my forked gem5 for anyone who wants to see the code details: https://gitlab.com/muke101/pnd-loads/-/tree/main/gem5?ref_type=heads

Comment: Isn't the expected behaviour of these no-scan loads to get the contents of L1d cache (or trigger a cache miss) if they overlap an in-flight store?  So they wouldn't be safe to use on memory that this core has stored to since the last full barrier that drains the store buffer.  Of course, having the guest code load "bad" data is different from the simulator itself crashing.

Comment: You're right I should had specified the guest program crashes rather than Gem5 itself, I was still grasping with the problem when I wrote that. The expected behaviour is that these loads won't have dependencies within the same window, and so any stores they're dependent on will already have committed to cache when to go to access it. But we still check for violations to prevent creating an invalid program in case we're wrong.

Comment: Oh, I assume from a filename like `ARM/sim/faults.cc` that it was part of GEM5's simulation code.  Thanks for updating the title.

Comment: If the "CPU" still checks to make sure loads see earlier stores, what's the point?  Just to save power by not scanning the store buffer?  Or to avoid stalling false dependencies like Intel CPUs have when a load is exactly 4k away from a recent store?  So like a hint to the CPU to speculate non-dependent, if it couldn't be sure immediately.

Comment: It is - what was happening is that, some of the time, one of the special loads would be producing a pointer for another load to use, which could be garbage. The consuming load would then trigger a page table fault which gets dealt with in `faults.cc`.

Comment: The point of the research is mainly revolving around the memory dependence predictor, which uses store sets in Gem5, and what we can gain by skipping lookups into it. I also wanted to quantify how much we can reduce demand on searching the store queue too (which is a power save but also something architects get exciting about generally as the LSQ is hard to scale), as again we don't expect these loads to have forwarding cases anyway. If you're especially interested I can send you the paper when we finally have some results :)

Comment: One potential concern with loading data that you wouldn't normally want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitectural_Data_Sampling - An instruction like this could widen the attack surface for loading data that's microarchitecturally floating around, at least speculatively if you're always checking to maintain standard program-order semantics even if mis-used.  (Seems like it would be hard to save power in the store queue itself if you still need to detect every reload of an in-flight store, but hinting the dependency predictor makes sense.  And I guess saving power in access to it.)

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question with a link to your paper or a page about your results once you have some, that would be cool. (I'll probably see the edit and check it out). (And link a github fork of your modified Gem5 in your answer, for future readers to play with or use as an example of how to change stuff in that part of Gem5.)

Comment: Just added the repo, and sure I'll add the paper when it's out too. Your note on attack surface is true but we're trying to keep the scope to performance/power - can worry about other problems once we've established there's something on the table in the first place. As for LSQ power savings, we're not reducing bandwidth on the load queue true, which is where violations are checked for, but we are potentially really reducing bandwidth on the store queue, and going more cycles without having to touch it at all which is a big power gain.